# iPhone Obj-C Properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

I'm a beginner following a book for creating iPhone apps.

One of the steps was writing "UISwitch *whichSwitch = whichSwitch.isOn;" and I was just curious as to where "isOn" came from?

In the documentation:

```
on
A Boolean value that determines the off/on state of the switch.

@property(nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on
```

What does that "getter=isOn" part mean? My ultimate reason for asking this question is because I want to know what I should do when I come across a similar situation for different UI elements.

Oh yeah, is this like the thing where properties create a "setSomething" mutator and "something" accessor? Except that for booleans it is "isOn" and "on"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are basically shorthand for generating methods later (the actual creation is done by `@synthesize` directives in the implementation file). The `getter=isOn` inside the `@property` does indeed mean that the getter method has the name `isOn`.

Properties by default will create a getter with the *same name as the ivar* and a setter with `set` prepended. Changing the getter name (or its setter, with the `setter=` syntax) is all this property directive does. You should do this only for boolean or similar variables - other variables should have a getter with the same name as the variable.

Comment: and sorry, I just realized that this was probably an easy enough question that I could have just looked up...its just that I'm new and the documentation still scares me a bit

Comment: Don't be afraid of the docs - they can't hurt you :) if you're just starting out, the Objective-C Programming Language document is very helpful, especially (for this question) the part about Declared Properties: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Comment: The documentation is long-winded, but otherwise very accessible. Don't be afraid!

http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

The API documentation, on the other hand, leaves something to be desired.